# How to add webfonts and images loaders to webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I would like to include webfonts and image loader to my project. I have the following rules in my webpack config:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          outputPath: "./images",
          publicPath: "./images",
          name: "./[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    loader: "url-loader",
    options: {
      outputPath: "./webfonts",
      publicPath: "./webfonts",
      name: "./[name].[ext]",
    },
  },
```

But when I run `npm run build` it builds the webfonts into the /images folder in the dist folder. How can I prevent webpack from doing this?

Comment: It looks like `url-loader` doesn't write files to disk, it only transforms files into base64  which means there is no such option `outputPath`? You must have misunderstood?

Comment: can you explain more please :) im new to webpack

Comment: Just read this https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack to determine which loader is good for your app